# How to add custom github actions in a typescript projen project

Tags: typescript, github-actions

Is there a way to specify custom github actions for a typescript project in a `.projenrc.js` file? I've tried reading this documentation: https://github.com/projen/projen-github-action-typescript/blob/main/API.md but I couldn't find clear instructions on how to include my custom actions in the `TypeScriptProject`'s configuration options.

PS: I wanted to add the `projen` tag, but I don't have enough reputation to add.

Comment: Just to clarify, you have a custom GitHub Action written in TypeScript that you want to use. Is that correct?

Comment: No, it's a `TypeScriptProject` from the projen library and I want to add an action to one of the existing workflows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to add a custom github action in the `.projenrc.js` file in the following way:

```js
// .projenrc.js

const { typescript } = require('projen');

const project = new typescript.TypeScriptProject({
    ...config
});

const workflow = project.github.workflows.find((wf) => wf.name === 'release');

if (!!workflow) {
    workflow.addJob('job_name', { ...jobConfig }); // for job config: https://github.com/projen/projen/blob/65b4194c163f47ba4842981b0c92dbe516be787b/src/github/workflows-model.ts#L6
}
project.synth();
```